# Is it possible to use a TStringList where a filename was needed in reportbuilder

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder, tstringlist

I connect to a webservice to get data for our reports. After retrieval I save the data as a CSV file using Tstringlists's SaveToFile method and the pass this filename to the TppTextPipeline from ReportBuilder.

I would love if instead I just, somehow, told report builder to use the TStringList diretcly savign me a physical file to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a memory stream (TStrings.SavetoStream) and a TppJITPipeline instead of a TppTextPipeline.

Comment: I'll check it out! Unfortunately I have delivered the software but Ill still tru to experiment with this. Thanks a lot!